Importmap and Save page as in browser does not save js files
I'be built a rails 8 app with importmap.
I have pinned librairies such as bitcoinjs-lib, bip39 etc to generate keypairs on the frontend only.
# Pin npm packages by running ./bin/importmap

pin "application"
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/services", under: "services"

# ...

# Bitcoin-related dependencies
pin "bitcoinjs-lib", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:bitcoinjs-lib@6.1.7/src/index.js"
pin "@noble/hashes/crypto", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@noble/hashes@1.6.1/crypto.js"
pin "@noble/hashes/ripemd160", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@noble/hashes@1.6.1/ripemd160.js"

However when I "Save page as" with my browser : all the js librairies are not downloaded
$ ls ~/Downloads/Bitcoin Hong Bao - Print Bitcoin Bills for Red Envelopes _files
active_admin-50cc70bd.css         es-module-shims.js                
script.js
application-8b441ae0.css          inter-font-1d90a608.css           
tailwind-5b090eeb.css
application.tailwind-75b7eec2.css mtp-widget.js

Seems like for browser to save the files they need to be included as javascript_include_tag.
Is there a way to handle it with importmap or I have to use esbuild to compile / transpile the js to be able to have a standlone version ?
